# Limited number of objects when creating dynamic array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a sample code to create array of objects (from a abstract class). I have written my code like this

```
VehicleManagement::VehicleManagement() {

    this->number0fVehicles = 7;
    this->vehicle = new Vehicle*[this->number0fVehicles];
}
```

[image]

but I am not getting the expected result, I only get 5 places instead of 7 places. Please tell me how should I modify my code. Or if there is any other simple way to do it please let me know Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `std::vector`?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, this is homework restriction

Comment: No, you got an array of seven. The debugger only has a pointer to work with, and pointers can't be used to determine if they are pointing into an array. It shows you 5 items as a heuristic. It doesn't really know how many items can be accessed by the pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Good to know Thank you!